# Dynamically update grid-list material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a react project. I am trying to implement grid-list component of material ui. I have an array of image urls. I render images in grid-list from this array. Now I have an add button which allows me to add urls to this array. So the state if array changes to a new array with added urls. I want my grid-list to show the new images also with the old images. Here is my code

```
state = {
        imageURLS: ["https://www.r.te.com/api/v1/frames/c6180ce1-2260-4bed-800f-c2325e6242e0/"]
    };

updateImageURLS(url_array) {
        this.setState({
            imageURLS: url_array     //url_array is the new array with added urls
        })
        this.componentWillUpdate();
    }

<div className="image-grid" style={styles.root}>
                    <GridList style={styles.gridList} cols={3}>
                        {this.state.imageURLS.map((x,i) => (
                            <GridTile
                                key={x}
                                //title={tile.title}
                                //actionIcon={<IconButton><StarBorder color="rgb(0, 188, 212)" /></IconButton>}
                                //titleStyle={styles.titleStyle}
                                //titleBackground="linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 70%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)"
                            >
                                <img src={x} />
                            </GridTile>
                        ))}
                    </GridList>
                </div>
```

Every time the state changes, my list should add new images to it. How can I do it?

**UPDATE:** Just more information on array

I have an upload form which when submitted, saves the image url (azure blob url) in an array. I push the new image ur to that array everytime I upload a new image. Now I set array passed (array_url) in the argument is the array (pushed with new image URLS) coming from there, Now I set imageURLS array equal to array_url in the above code. That is how I am doing it. I have included the code in update.

```
 $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {
          

          
            imageURL = response.blob_url; 

            url_array.push(response.blob_url)   //new image url added to array

            that.uploadImage();

        });

  uploadImage() {
        var that = this;
        var uri = submitUri
        console.log(uri);
        var requestBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><BlockList>';
        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            processData:false,
            type: "PUT",
            data: selectedFile,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
                //xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-content-type', selectedFile.type);
                //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', requestBody.length);
            },
            success: function (data, status) {
                               fileIndex = fileIndex + 1;
                if(fileIndex==files.length){
                 
                    that.props.updateImageURLS(url_array);    //when all files gets uploaded, call this fuction to update the url array to show iamges 
                }
                else {
                    that.sendURL();
                    that.handleUpload(fileIndex);
                }


            },
            error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(desc);
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

Now When I add a url, it shows default html icon for image, and not the actual image.
[image]

Comment: Please don't call `this.componentWillUpdate()` directly. Please show us code where you add url to the array.

Comment: So it comes from an upload form. I have an upload form which when submitted, saves the image url (azure blob url) in an array. I push the new image ur to that array everytime I upload a new image. Now I set array passed (array_url) in the argument is the array (pushed with new image URLS) coming from there, Now I set imageURLS array equal to array_url in the above code. That is how I am doing it. I have included the code in update.